# Pass google script value to external website(non google)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've created a website where I call a googlescript macro from an Iframe to upload file.

I´m able to get `file.getUrl();` to console.log but I want to know is there a way to pass this info to a var in my website(non google)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/). There quickstarts for several languages, maybe [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js) it's the one that will find most helpful.